# Extrange "methodNotAllowed" error

Tags: laravel

- Laravel Version: 5.3.31

#### Description:

I have the exact same ajax call on two diferente pages of my project but im getting an "methodNotAllowed" error in one of them.

My web.php:

```
Route::post('/seccion', 'FiltrosController@getSecciones')->name("filtro.secciones");
```

My AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: "{{ route("filtro.secciones") }}",
       data: $("#form").serialize(),
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (datos) {
           //mycode
       },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
           console.log(error);
       }
   });
```

Here is the header of the call that works:

```
Request URL:http://192.168.99.100:3001/seccion
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.99.100:3001
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

And the response header that i get:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:457
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 07 Aug 2017 19:26:43 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97
Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
```

Ok in this case all works. But then in the other page, i make the same ajax call and im getting this:

```
Request URL:http://192.168.99.100:3001/seccion
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address:192.168.99.100:3001
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

And the response header of the call that fails:

```
allow:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 07 Aug 2017 19:26:57 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.7
```

We can see POST is allowed in the response header but im getting this "Code:405 Method Not Allowed"

I dont know what is happing, any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: The AJAX code that works is the same as the code that does not work?

Comment: Log the data: `console.log($("#form").serialize())`.

Comment: Laerte yes its exact the same ajax. In fact one Page is a copy/paste of the other with minor changes

Comment: Deavon i already check the form. And its serialized without problems. Thanks!

Comment: Does the form that fails have an input with the name "_method"?

Comment: Patricus, im going to check tomorrow, but as you can see here:

    Request URL:http://192.168.99.100:3001/seccion
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed   
    Remote Address:192.168.99.100:3001
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

it says request method POST in the header that ajax sends.

Comment: @LeonardoCabré In order to allow for handling PUT, PATCH, and DELETE requests, Laravel allows for method spoofing using the `_method` request variable. So, your form (or ajax) does an HTTP POST, but the spoofed method is determined by the `_method` request value. So, if you POST a form that has the input data `_method=PUT` (or any other value), then Laravel will use that as the method to check for when resolving routes.

Comment: @patricus and Laerte thanks for you help, i can test what you pointed me and you are right.
i have a "_method: PATCH" in my data, it make sense because one of the "minor changes" that i said i did, was put {{ method_field('PATCH') }} in my form that wraps my "dropdown select", that fires the ajax call.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i put "{{ method_field('PATCH') }}" in the form that wraps the select dropdown that fires the ajax call, so a _method parameter with "PATCH" value is passed in the data of the ajax call and throws the "methodNotAllowed" error.

I fixed it just passing the data i need and not all the form serialized:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "{{ route("filtro.secciones") }}",
    data: $("#form").find('#zonas').serialize(),//<-- solution 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (datos) {
        //my code
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log(error);         
    }
});
```